# KDE application icon not displayed in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, icons, kde-apps

Some icons are missing from a KDE application (Okular) in Ubuntu.

How could this be fixed?

```
Opening okular from terminal shows:
android@android:~$ okular
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/snap/communitheme/current/share/icons/Suru/256x256@2x/apps/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/snap/communitheme/current/share/icons/Suru/256x256@2x/mimetypes/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/snap/communitheme/current/share/icons/Suru/scalable/mimetypes/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/snap/communitheme/current/share/icons/Suru/256x256@2x/apps/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/snap/communitheme/current/share/icons/Suru/256x256@2x/mimetypes/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/snap/communitheme/current/share/icons/Suru/scalable/mimetypes/"
```

[image]

Comment: It's probably because you don't have whatever icon theme that that program uses installed on your system. Try opening okular from the terminal and post the initial output you receive upon opening the program. I'd like to see if there are any errors.

Comment: i posted the errors above @Emandudeguy

Comment: I have the same problem; must be some icon theme not installed. I tried installing `plasma-theme-oxygen`, but then I can't find how to change the theme for kde apps...

Comment: You should try `sudo apt-get install qt5-style-plugins`

Answer (score 2):

First install `qt5ct`:

```
sudo apt install qt5ct
```

Then run it and choose your preferred icon/theme:

[image]

Finally set `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME` to `qt5ct` in your `.profile`:

```
echo 'export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct' >> $HOME/.profile
```

Re-login and  it should fix the issue.