# Could not start kmplayer using desktop menu launcher

Tags: 19.04, 19.10, dock, budgie

I use [Budgie DM](https://ubuntubudgie.org) on Ubuntu 19.10 (firstly noticed on 19.04).

I've installed kmplayer using

```
sudo apt install kmplayer
```

When I run kmplayer from terminal: `$ kmplayer`, it runs successfully throwing only:

```
 Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Faba/symbolic/mimetypes/"
 Icon theme "elementary" not found.
```

I can drag and drop videos into it and it plays them.

But when I try to open kmplayer using desktop menu, its icon appears on dock panel and disappears after 15 seconds without main window opening.

Also, when I try to open a video using **Context menu -> Open with -> Kmplayer** it behaves the same wrong way.

Gnome MPV, VLC, Parole Media Player open videos without issues.

KMPlayer version: 0.12.0b (c) 2002-2016, Koos Vriezen

Why could it be opened by terminal command and 
could not be opened by *Menu item* clicking or by opening video using *Open with* context menu clicking?

Comment: what is that for? it's just a plugin

Comment: kmplayer 0.12.0.b-3
    Video player plugin for Konqueror and basic MPlayer/Xine/ffmpeg/ffserver/VDR
    frontend for KDE

Comment: as for the KDE icon theme it is something related to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007563/kde-application-icon-not-displayed-in-ubuntu

Comment: If you simply need a video player just go with SMPlayer it saves you lots of pain.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for explanation! But I'm curious about it. Why it could be launched with correct icon displayed when started from terminal and could not be launched through GUI?

Comment: that is because you are launching KDE application on Gnome desktop environment, you might be missing KDE icon themes or plugins required by kmplayer.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking, but why does it work correctly when I run it using terminal command: `kmplayer`?

Answer (score 2):

It can't start by clicking the menu item because KDE launches it with additional options.

To fix that:

1. Open KDE Menu Editor.
2. Find the KMPlayer item.
3. Change the `Command` entry with `kmplayer` without any options.

That works for me.